# How to start triton server after building the Windows 10 "Min" Image?

Tags: nvidia, windows-server-2019, rapidjson, tritonserver

I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/a37a6e2fafc651800f211265bdda8ef1293d7a1b/docs/customization_guide/build.md#windows-10-min-image).

I am able to build the win10-py3-min image.

After that I am trying to build the Triton Server as mentioned [here](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/a37a6e2fafc651800f211265bdda8ef1293d7a1b/docs/customization_guide/build.md#building-with-specific-github-branches)

Command:

```
python build.py -v --no-container-pull --image=gpu-base,win10-py3-min --enable-logging --enable-stats --enable-tracing --enable-gpu --endpoint=grpc --endpoint=http --repo-tag=common:r22.10 --repo-tag=core:r22.10 --repo-tag=backend:r22.10 --repo-tag=thirdparty:r22.10 --backend=ensemble --backend=tensorrt:r22.10
```

I am getting error as below.

```
cmake : The term 'cmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\workspace\build\cmake_build.ps1:20 char:1 + cmake "-DTRT_VERSION4{env:TRT_VERSION}" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${en +..—+ Categorylnfo : ObjectNotFound: (cmake:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorld : CommandNotFoundException

DEBUG: 86+ >>>> ExitWithCode 1;
DEBUG: 6+ function ExitWithCode($exitcode) >>>>
DEBUG: 7+ >>>> $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
DEBUG: 8+ >>>> exit $exitcode


DEBUG: 33+ if ( >>>> $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
DEBUG: 34+ >>>> Write-Output "exited with status code $LASTEXITCODE-; exited with status code 1
DEBUG: 35+ >>>> ExitWithCode 1;
DEBUG: 6+ function ExitWithCode($exitcode) >>>>
DEBUG: 7+ >>>> $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
DEBUG: 8+ >>>> exit $exitcode error: build failed
```

and for below command

```
python build.py -v --no-container-pull --image=base,win10-py3-min --enable-logging --enable-stats --enable-tracing --enable-gpu --endpoint=grpc --endpoint=http --repo-tag=common:r22.10 --repo-tag=core:r22.10 --repo-tag=backend:r22.10 --repo-tag=thirdparty:r22.10 --backend=ensemble --backend=tensorrt:r22.10
```

getting error as below.

```
"C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\install.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\ALL_BUILO.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
(CustomBuild target) -> C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\_deps\repo-common-src\include\triton/common/triton_json.h(641,35): error 02039: 'GetObjectA': is not a member of 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<c har>,rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>>1 [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\triton-core.vcxproll [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core .vcxproj]
C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\_deps\repo-common-src\include\triton/common/triton_json.h(641,1): error 02530: 'm': references must be initialized [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_ deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\triton-core.vcxproj] [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core.vcxproj]
C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\_deps\repo-common-src\include\triton/common/triton_json.h(641,1): error C3531: 'm': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an initializer [C:\tmp\tr itonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\triton-core.vcxproj] [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core.vcxproj]
C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\_deps\repo-common-src\include\triton/common/triton_json.h(641,26): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':' [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build \_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\triton-core.vcxproj] [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core.vcxproj]
C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\_deps\repo-common-src\include\triton/common/triton_json.h(641,46): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'y [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build \_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core\triton-core.vcxproj] [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\triton-core.vcxproj]
C:\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(238,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\6f6d31a7577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-mkdir.rule;C:\tmp\triton build\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\6f6d31a7577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-download.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\6f6d31a7577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-update.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonser ver\build\CMakeFiles\6f6d310577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-patch.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\6f6d310577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-configure.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMake Files\6f6d31a7577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-build.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\6f6d31a7577427f4fd89bcde8fd28163\triton-core-install.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\e0e8eabd6eb cadfabbd7ced13e471b12\triton-core-complete.rule;C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\CMakeFiles\d677bfcd41cd12f160cbc1390c778655\triton-core.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\tmp\tritonbuild\tritonserver\build\_deps\repo-core-build\ triton-core.vcxproj]

2021 Warning(s)
6 Error(s)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage using **images** for represent textual information. Instead, paste the error messages into the question post as **text** and format them accordingly. Also, aside from *referring* to the guides you are following, add to the question **exact steps** you have **actually performed**. It could be that you forgot to perform some step, or perform it incorrectly. See also [ask].

Comment: The first error is about absent of `cmake` utility. Have you installed it? The documentation you refers to clearly states that Triton server is built using CMake. The second error message smells like about macro definition `GetObject` in `windows.h`: it defines the macro to value `GetObjectA`, so every method with name `GetObject` is automatically "renamed". Like in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223854/getobject-getobjecta-linker-error).

Answer (score 0):

1. Run **Visual Studio Installer** and ensure you have installed **C++ CMake tools for Windows**.
   [image: Visual Studio Installer]
2. Run **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2019**
3. Run in the command prompt:

   ```
   python build.py -v --no-container-pull --image=gpu-base,win10-py3-min --enable-logging --enable-stats --enable-tracing --enable-gpu --endpoint=grpc --endpoint=http --repo-tag=common:r22.10 --repo-tag=core:r22.10 --repo-tag=backend:r22.10 --repo-tag=thirdparty:r22.10 --backend=ensemble --backend=tensorrt:r22.10
   ```

Comment: I have already installed C++ CMake tools for Windows. Still it is giving the same error.